# How do I make my paypal payment redirect on success?

Tags: javascript, button, paypal, next.js, router

I'm trying to code something with the npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js

But it either is not reading the code, or the code isn't redirecting back. I'm using next/router for the redirect. please help.

```js
    const onApprove = (data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            const { payer } = details;
      const router = useRouter();
            setBillingDetails(payer);
            setSucceeded(true);
            router.push("https://duke-bot.com")
        });
    };
```

EDIT: The Payment redirects back to the page I was previously on, aka the checkout page, but it doesnt read the other page's redirect

Comment: `const router = useRouter();` is a custom hook and needs to be declared at the top level of your React component.

Comment: @juliomalves It doesnt change anything, gives me an error on page entry instead

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @juliomalves 
"Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: next_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...) is not a function"

Comment: Can you show the full code for that file?